# ASP.NET vNext Kestrel + windows authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linux, kestrel-http-server

I installed an ASP.NET web application onto a linux system, which works fine, I can browse every content. Now I am wondering, if there is any possibility or workaround to use windows authentication scheme with the Kestrel server? As I can see after searching on google that this isn't supported at the moment.

Thanks for the answers.

**EDIT:**

However windows authentication not working in Kestrel, I was able to get the user name by implementing an NTLM authentication's challenge-response protocol in my webb app.

Based on https://loune.net/2009/09/ntlm-authentication-in-php-now-with-ntlmv2-hash-checking/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I accept, that windows authentication is not available in Linux, but using the link in my question we can write a custom ActionFilterAttribute, which makes the NTLM authentication process:

```
public async override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var controller = (ControllerBase)filterContext.Controller;
    if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        if (!(await IsAuthorized(filterContext.HttpContext, controller)))
        {
            filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(401);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //TODO check access rights
    }
}

private async Task<bool> IsAuthorized(HttpContext context, ControllerBase controller)
{
    if (!context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate", "NTLM");
        return false;
    }

    var header = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"][0].Substring(5);
    var message = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                      Convert.FromBase64String(header));
    if (!message.StartsWith("NTLMSSP"))
    {
        return false;
    }

    //type 1 message received
    if (message[8] == '\x01')
    {
        byte[] type2Message =
        {
            0x4e, 0x54, 0x4c, 0x4d, 0x53, 0x53, 0x50, 0x00,//Signature
            0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, //Type 2 Indicator
            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, //Security Buffer
            0x01, 0x02, 0x81, 0x00, //Flags
            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, //Challenge
            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, //Context
            0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 //Target info
        };
        context.Response.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate", "NTLM "
            + Convert.ToBase64String(type2Message));
        return false;
    }
    //type 3 message received
    else if (message[8] == '\x03')
    {
        var userName = GetMessageString(message, 36);
        var domainName = GetMessageString(message, 28);
        var workstation = GetMessageString(message, 44);

        var user = controller.DbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(
                      u => u.WindowsAccount.ToLower() == userName.ToLower());
        if (user != null)
        {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity();
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName));
            context.User.AddIdentity(identity);

            try
            {
                await controller.SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, false);
            }
            catch { }

            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

private string GetMessageString(string message, int start, bool unicode = true)
{
    var length = message[start + 1] * 256 + message[start];
    var offset = message[start + 5] * 256 + message[start + 4];
    if (unicode)
        return message.Substring(offset, length).Replace("\0", "");
    else
        return message.Substring(offset, length);
}
```

Comment: Could there be any similar approach that would support Kerberos ?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, IIS/ASP.NET relies on the Windows API to perform Windows authentication. Such API does not exist on Linux, so Kestrel won't support Windows authentication, unless some day Microsoft engineers fill the gaps.