# Is it possible to authenticate user with Kerberos in Asp.Net MVC app manualy?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kerberos

Is it possible to authenticate request manualy with Kerberos using native apis, without delegating this stuff to IIS?
For example use kerberos.dll or SSPI on Windows and libkrb5 on Linux?

Possible scenarios I am researching now are:

Asp.Net MVC + IIS
Asp.Net Core + Kestrel behind IIS
Asp.Net Core + Kestrel behind HAProxy or Nginx

I want to support same behavior like WindowsAuthentication=Enabled on IIS.
Maybe someone could point me in right direction?

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34956808/asp-net-vnext-kestrel-windows-authentication) answer, but it covers NTLM stuff.

Comment: Yes, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40944092/how-do-i-handle-negotiate-in-net/41035145#41035145
You can use Secur32.dll on windows at least. I am not familiar with libkrb5.