# How do I handle Negotiate in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, kerberos, sspi

I'm trying to implement Negotiate (at least the Kerberos part) in a small web server. I've figured out how to get a client to send me a Kerberos Negotiate Authorization header. I've figured out how to decode that data (ASN.1). I cannot figure out how to turn this into a `WindowsIdentity`. I can get a general idea of how I might from [`KerberosReceiverSecurityToken`](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.IdentityModel/System/IdentityModel/Tokens/KerberosReceiverSecurityToken.cs), but I can't find anything like a `NegotiateReceiverSecurityToken`. I've been digging through lots of DLLs and I can't for the life of me figure out where IIS/.NET processes the Negotiate header.

I presume (if I had my own `SspiWrapper`) that I would do something with `SspiWrapper.AcquireDefaultCredential("Negotiate", CredentialUse.Inbound)` to acquire an SSPI context with which I could call [`AcceptSecurityContext/Negotiate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374705(v=vs.85).aspx) and then use [`QuerySecurityContextToken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379355(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the token with which I could create a `WindowsIdentity`.

But `KerberosReceiverSecurityToken` makes that look like an immensely complicated process. And without any idea of how to do that or what part of the Authorization header payload to put into it, I could probably beat my head against it for a month without getting anywhere.

(Before you ask or answer, I have absolutely no interest in using the built in Negotiate logic. If I could find it, I would learn from it, but I've been trying to get that to work for FAR to long. And I'm done with that.)

Comment: You will have to refer to Katana/Kestrel web server source code repo from Microsoft to learn which native API they call. It is rather a broad question I am voting to close. If you do intend to build your own, Microsoft published the standard documents at its site which you'd better Google.

Comment: @LexLi How is my question broad? I want to take the data sent to my server from a client and turn it into a WindowsPrincipal. Seems pretty darn specific to me.

Comment: a protocol client implementation is a huge project and how much do you expect a thread at Stack Overflow to offer?

Comment: I'm not trying to build a protocol implementation. I'm simply trying to decode the negotiate header and do something useful with the result. Based on `KerberosReceiverSecurityToken`, that should be ~100 lines and 10-20 SSPI API calls.

Comment: I have implemented this using BouncyCastle (c#) for the ASN.1 stuff.

Comment: i'd love to know if you or @Sense545 ever built this out...

Comment: I made a working implementation in 2013 using the methods mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Parse the incoming response token
2. Call `Secur32.AcquireCredentialsHandle` to get a handle
3. Call `Secur32.AcceptSecurityContext` passing the handle and the token
4. Call `Secur32.QuerySecurityContextToken` passing the security context
5. Construct a `new WindowsIdentity(hToken)` using the output form step 4

If you have any questions about any of these steps, I can elaborate and/or provide some sample code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I have some time, I'll try to use this to solve my problem. I'll get back to you then.