# Service Fabric - Windows - Kerberos Authentication

Tags: angular, authentication, kestrel, weblistener

I was involved in the architecture desgin for an enterprise application. I decided to adopt the Microservices Approach and I decided to use Service Fabric as infrastructure on premises to deploy and manage the application. Briefly, I am going to develop an Angular2 Front End hosted on Kestrel (or WebListener) and I was wondering how I can implement the Windows authentication in order to allow to the user to authenticate simply inserting their domain credentials.

I didn't find any documentation about it. Is there a way like IIS ti set the type of authentication on service fabric?

Thanks in advance,
Giuseppe

Answer (score 0):

The probable reason for your question sitting unanswered is I don't think you are asking the right question.

Awesome, you're using Service Fabric (me too), but you're confusing the hosting of your application from application specific functionality (auth). Service Fabric is a service hosting environment, it's up to you what you put in it.

Ok, so you want an Angular2 Front End. Are you intending on putting your front end in Service Fabric? Because you don't have to, but let me assume that you are, your auth requirement should be baked into your web project serving your Angular 2 files. In which case, you should be looking for windows Auth in Kestral.

I know next to nothing about Kerberos but perhaps the above and this may be helpful:
[How do I handle Negotiate in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40944092/how-do-i-handle-negotiate-in-net/41035145#41035145)

And this for creating your Angular 2 Service fabric shell service:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-add-a-web-frontend

Comment: Hi Adam,thanks for you answer. Why I shouldn't put the front end in service fabric?

Comment: There is no technical reason. It would be based on other operational factors which for green fields development are unlikely.